# Configure multiple roles with same permissions

Tags: arrays, drupal, permissions

I've got a quite large website with over 20 roles and permissions. However, it are always the same permissions, but depending on who created the content, the permissions differ...

So what I do now is this:

```
    // Make the new role
    $role = new stdClass;
    $role->name = 'Redacteur 1';
    $role->weight = 3;
    user_role_save($role);

    // Permissions to assign to the role.
    // Note these are defined in hook_permission()
    $perms = array(
    'access content','access content overview'
    );

    // Grant the permissions. This function takes care of all necessary cache resets
    user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $perms);

    // Make the new role
    $role = new stdClass;
    $role->name = 'Redacteur 2';
    $role->weight = 3;
    user_role_save($role);

    // Permissions to assign to the role.
    // Note these are defined in hook_permission()
    $perms = array(
    'access content','access content overview'
    );

    // Grant the permissions. This function takes care of all necessary cache resets
    user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $perms);
```

Isn't there a way to do this with some kind of array so I don't end up with a 1000 line of code. When you want to change something in the permissions, you have to revise all the roles... This must be easier to do. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some default function to acomplish this goal:

```
function _load_permission_settings($role_index = null) {
    // Blocks
    $perms['administer blocks'] =           array(0, 0, 0);
    // Comments
    $perms['administer comments'] =         array(0, 1, 0);
    $perms['access comments'] =             array(1, 1, 1);
    $perms['post comments'] =               array(1, 1, 1);
    $perms['skip comment approval'] =       array(1, 1, 1);
    $perms['edit own comments'] =           array(1, 1, 1);
        ...


function _create_users() {
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');

    $roles = user_roles(true);

    $users[] = array('an', array(3));
    $users[] = array('ben', array(4, 6, 8));
    ...

function _set_roles_and_permissions() {
    // Enable default permissions for system roles.
    user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID, array('access content'));
    user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, _load_permission_settings(0));

    // Permissions to assign to the roles. (all Thema-related roles share the same permissions)
    $perms_eind = _load_permission_settings(1);
    $perms_red = _load_permission_settings(2);

    $user_roles = _load_thema_user_role_names('');
    foreach ($user_roles as $name) {
        // Role1
            $role = new stdClass;
        $role->name = 'Role 1 - ' . $name;
        user_role_save($role);
        user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $perms_eind);
        // Role2
        $role = new stdClass;
        $role->name = 'Role 2 - ' . $name;
        user_role_save($role);
        user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $perms_red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the fields in the database. I wish I could help you more but I have only done minor adjustments.